# Auto-completion visual not good (readline.h)

Tags: c, shell, autocomplete

I would like to add the auto completion on the shell I created. I could not put the entire code but I can tell you my shell is working! 
So I tried to implement auto-completion by using the readline function but the result is not that great (see the code in commentary I tried): the auto-completion works but the problems are:
1. I need to press twice enter to get the command executed now. 2. I need to type twice the command (like "ls") to get it executed! Can you help me to fix this? thank you :)

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "includes/ft_sh1.h"

int main(int ac, char **av, char **envp)
{
    char    *line;
    t_env   *e = NULL;
    char *add;

    if (!(e = (t_env *)malloc(sizeof(t_env))))
        return (0);
    e->envp = env_cpy(envp, 0, 0);
    init_env(e);
    while (1)
    {

--> My question is only about this part below <--

        ft_printf("shell$> ");

     //   add =  readline( "shell ");
     //   add_history(add);
     //   printf("%s", add);

--> My question is only about this part above <--


        get_next_line(0, &line);
        get_pwd_env(e);
        e->cmd = get_cmd(e, line);
        if (ft_strcmp(line, "exit") == 0)
            exit(0);
        else if (ft_strncmp(e->cmd[0], "cd", 2) == 0)
            cd_cmd(e);
        else
            ft_execute(av, line, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just uncomment the part of code in question, you still have the call

```
        get_next_line(0, &line);
```

in your program, so no wonder that you need to type two command lines.